# Ubuntu increase disk partition (LEFT side)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted, disk

I have dual boot Ubuntu 14 (first half of hard disk) and Ubuntu 16 (Second half). I tried to increase the size of Ubuntu 16 using Gparted. But, I was not able to move/drag the partition of Ubuntu16 to the LEFT SIDE (Got warning that I might have booting issue)

Any way to resolve this?

[image: Gparted window Image]

I want to increase /dev/sda6 to use unallocated space on the Left side.

Comment: The above should also have clarified that you need to move it to the left, then grow it to the right and after that grow the logical partitions inside. **This operation is far more risky than simply growing. Make sure you have backups.**

Comment: @user68186   I will using Gparted from Ubuntu-14 (first half) and play with Ubuntu-16.
My only concern was boot issue.
I am working with my Lab_Computer. So, I want to take a extra step and make sure everything is correct (Booting issues, UUIDs and GRUB update)